# Count unique combinations in List R

Tags: r, list, count

I am working with the following  problem. I have a list with different size and I wanna count the occurrence of the words but join the same combinations like that:

```
[[1]]
"Room" "Residential 
[[2]]
"Residential" "Room" 
[[3]]
"Garage"
[[4]]
"Room" "Residential" "Comercial"
```

Results - 
combn | value

```
'Room, Residential': 2
'Garage': 1
"Room, Residential, Comercial': 1
```

Any ideas?

DATA

```
list(c("Room", "Residential"), c("Residential", "Room"), "Garage", 
     c("Room", "Residential", "Comercial"))
```

Comment: What about a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
res = lapply(L, function(x) paste(sort(unique(x)), collapse = ","))
```

This will sort the values according to some order and combine the values with a comma, where `L` is your list;

```
table(unlist(res))
```

This will give you the number of unique combinations